# Unable to serialize org.javers.core.diff.changetype.ValueChange object by spring-beans while retrieving ValueChange object from mongoDB

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, javers

I am storing change object in mongoDB database to, it is getting saved can see in db, but while retrieving back from mongoDB collection in application, getting below error:

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate org.javers.core.diff.changetype.ValueChange using constructor NO_CONSTRUCTOR with arguments
        at org.springframework.data.convert.ReflectionEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ReflectionEntityInstantiator.java:64) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.4.RELEASE.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.data.convert.ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:83) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.4.RELEASE.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:258) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.23.RELEASE.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:238) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.23.RELEASE.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readCollectionOrArray(MappingMongoConverter.java:930) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.23.RELEASE.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:220) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.23.RELEASE.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readMap(MappingMongoConverter.java:983) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.23.RELEASE.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:224) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.23.RELEASE.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1228) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.23.RELEASE.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.access$200(MappingMongoConverter.java:84) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.23.RELEASE.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$MongoDbPropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1176) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.23.RELEASE.jar:?]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that storing Changes somewhere is a lagal use case for Javers. JaversRepository stores only Snapshots and it works out of the box.